# Creating Custom Object Record with Salesforce Connector

Tags: crm

I'm new to Drupal's Salesforce webform plugin. Can someone tell me what type of Salesforce Records a Drupal form can create? Is it limited to Lead and Case? Or can it create any standard or custom object? Thanks!